# How to get the session value in ejs

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am making a login module using session(using express and nodes).
When the user has logged in, I save the user in the session.

```
req.session.user= ...
```

How can I get the session value in a .ejs view like:

```
<label>
            您好！<%= req.session.user.username %>
 </label>
```

But this doesn't work.

I can do it by this:

```
router.get('/home',function(req, res){

    var val = req.session.user;
    res.render('home',{user:val});


});
```

.ejs:

```
<p>
            您好！<%= user.username %>
</p>
```

But this is so troublesome.
What is the better way to do it?

(In php, I can just use $_SESSION to get the value in a view file.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) to expose particular data to all templates.

In your situation, you could add the following middleware to Express:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.session.user;
  next();
});
```

This will make a `user` variable available in all your templates.

You do need to make sure that you add that middleware *after* `req.session` has been set (which is usually after `express-session` has been added to the middleware chain).

Comment: Thanks a lot. By your help, I have solved my problem.

Comment: @BrunoCanongia `res.locals.res = res` might work (although it sounds like a recipe for memory leaks…)

Comment: @robertklep, thank you, man! I was trying to access res.locals.currentUser in my template. All I needed was currentUser directly.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you! you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

```
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.email = req.session.email;
  res.locals.firstName = req.session.firstName;
  res.locals.lastName = req.session.lastName;
  next();
});
    
    //esj file use:-
    <div class="media-body">
       <h5 class="mt-0 mb-0"><%=lastName%> <%=firstName%></h5>
       <span><%=email%></span>
    </div>
```