# How can I access session data in an EJS template with a node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, node-modules

I have created a dynamic menubar based on the user's role. On the server side, when the user is logged in I am storing all their allowed pages in their session.

Now, I have 15 templates. I have included `menubar.html` file on each and every page. I want to use session data in `menubar.html` without having to pass it explicitly each time.

I have tried the following code:

```
app.get('/home',function(req,res)){
  res.render('home',{menu : req.session.menubar})
}
app.get('/contact',function(req,res)){
  res.render('contact',{menu : req.session.menubar})
}
```

In above code, I need to pass session data on every page. If I have 50 html templates, it's not efficient to pass the session in each and every route.

What is the best approach to handle this?

Comment: you have to use -#{menu}

Comment: Thanks #Deep. can u describe how to use #{menu} ?

Comment: Is req.session.menubar array or just a string ? and is this a json ? It will be better if you share the value of req.session.menubar in your question.

Comment: array like this req.session.menubar = ['/home','/contact']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Are you including your HTML files as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753620/ejs-engine-with-html-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top)?
2. Assuming you are using [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), you may also need to set up middleware to assign session information to the **response** (`res`), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183766/how-to-get-the-session-value-in-ejs?answertab=votes#tab-top).

**app.js**:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: "sosecret",
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false
}));

// middleware to make 'user' available to all templates
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.session.user;
  next();
});
```

Then try referring to `res.locals.user` rather than the request object.

Comment: Its working fine you when render the view. But suppose if we call ajax and on success if you reload the page. It will not reflect in view.

Answer (score 0):

Since `EJS` is based on escaping to `JavaScript`, rendering lists can be done using the loop constructs in the language.

To display the value of array on your ejs template, you can use the following code:

```
<ul class="menubar">
  <% for(var i=0; i < menu.length; i++) { %>
     <li class="menu-title">
        <%= menu[i] %>
     </li>
  <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it on every templates, you need to store the session on database collections first. You use `connect-mongo` package for that. From the docs:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```