# change login to logout

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to change login button to logout when ctx.session.userID have value, I try to use ejs engine, but it didn't work, is there any problem, or other better way. This is server.js:

```
const M = require('./model')
const Koa = require('koa')
var serve = require('koa-static')
const session = require('koa-session')
var KoaRouter = require('koa-router')
var koaLogger = require('koa-logger')
const koaBody = require('koa-body')
const views = require('koa-views')
var app = new Koa()
const router = new KoaRouter()
app.use(views('view', {map:{html:'ejs'}})) 
app.use(koaLogger())
app.use(koaBody())
app.use(router.routes())
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public'));
app.keys = ['*@&))9kdjafda;983'] 
const CONFIG = { 
  key: 'd**@&(_034k3q3&@^(!$!',
  maxAge: 86400000
}
app.use(session(CONFIG, app)) 
router
.get('/', async (ctx) => {
    let title = 'ejs test'
    let userid = ctx.session.userID
    await ctx.render('index',{
        title, userid
    })
})

.post('/login', login)

.get('/error', async (ctx)=> {
    await ctx.render('error',{})
})

async function login(ctx){
    let {id, password} = ctx.request.body
    console.log("test:",id,password)
    if ( await M.get(id,password) != null){
        ctx.session.userID = id
        ctx.redirect('/')
        console.log('login success')
    }
    else {
        ctx.redirect('/error')
    }
}
```

And this is a part of index.html:

```
            <% if (userid == null){ %>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>   
            <% } else { %>
            <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
            <% } %>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37183766/438992

Comment: Noting also that even if it worked like you think `userid` is not the same variable as `userID`.

Comment: There are some inconsistencies; I see `session.userId` in the base `'/'` route and `session.userID` in the `login` function. They should be the same unless you intend to use them as different things.

Comment: Hey, I correct that ```session.userId```error. But login link still not change, and I use ```console.log``` to check ```session.userID``` status. After I post login, it still print ```undefined```

Answer (score 0):

In your `get('/')` route function, you are not using the same session variable you set in your `login()` function. Change the `get('/')` function to `let userid = ctx.session.userID` with the capital `ID` and log it to the console before sending to the template to make sure the variable is indeed set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using session in this application.
In the index.html you can check whether the status is logged in or not by using following Ejs code:

```html
<li id="login">
    <a href="<%= logStatus==='out'?'login':'logout'%>">
        <%= logStatus==='out'?'LOGIN':'LOGOUT'%>
    </a>
</li>
```

After this you can pass the status of login and logout through the Node.js, for each res.render() function you use in the Node.js code by following:

```js
res.render("[your route name]", { logStatus:`${req.session.user? 'in':'out'}` });
```

for Example:

```js
app.get("/upload", checkSignIn, (req, res) => {
  res.render("upload", { logStatus:`${req.session.user? 'in':'out'}` });
});
```

Note: Always pass the logStatus with every render to avoid error and you don't need to change anything in that, it will automatically check the status from session and send status.

If you have different name for session, then change it in the req.session.[name of the session].
for Example: if I have a session name like autoTocken then it will be like:

```js
app.get("/upload", checkSignIn, (req, res) => {
  res.render("upload", { logStatus:`${req.session.autoTocken ? 'in':'out'}` });
});
```

Comment: It appears you have not specified changing the `view-engine` to EJS.