# Send variables to all routes in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have `req.session` variables that I am setting upon login, like so:

```
req.session.loggedin = true
req.session.firstname = loginDetails.firstName;
```

what I want to do is pass this information to ALL routes (I have nearly 60, and don't want to go through all of them and add these in manually), and also every route I have calls the front-end using this:

```
res.render('page.ejs', {data: rows}), so I would ideally want it to pass it to the front-end pages so I can access them there too. Not sure if this is possible, but worth a shot! thx 4 the help in advance!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the session value in ejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183766/how-to-get-the-session-value-in-ejs)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a middleware function and add variables to an existing `express-session`.

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");

// express app
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// init example session with express session
app.use(session({ resave: true, secret: "123456", saveUninitialized: true }));

// use a middleware function
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.initialised) {
    // init variables you want to set in req.session
    req.session.loggedin = true;
    req.session.firstname = "john doe";
  }
  next();
});

// test api endpoint
app.use("/testroute", require("./routes/api/test"));

// run server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Then you can query your variables like `req.session.firstname` in any other route in the request object. You can also update it from your routes

**test.js**

```
// testroute
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  // get variables from request object
  try {
    console.log(req.session.firstname);
    console.log(req.session.loggedin);

    // this would update the session variable if uncommented
    // req.session.firstname = "dagobert"
    // console.log(req.session.firstname);
    res.status(200).json({ message: `Your firstname is ${req.session.firstname}` });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```